# shorthand if error when concatenating string

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string separator = " > ";

string retStr = "";

int count = 0;

foreach (string s in retList)
{
     count++;

     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
     {
         if (count < retList.Count)
             retStr += s + separator;
         else
             retStr += s;

             //count < retList.Count ? retStr += s + separator : retStr += s;
      }
}
```

Out-commented line results in error: `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`. Shouldnt that be eqvivalent to the if-case above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using this

```
retStr = count < retList.Count ? retStr + s + separator : retStr + s;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
retStr += s + separator
```

it should be:

```
someStringbuilder.append(s); someStringbuilder.append(separator);
```

at end of  your function:

```
  return someStringbuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

```
return String.Join(separator, retList);
```

From msdn:

> **String.Join**
>
> For example, if separator is ", " and the elements of value are
>   "apple", "orange", "grape", and "pear", Join(separator, value) returns
>   "apple, orange, grape, pear".
>
> If separator is null, an empty string (String.Empty) is used instead.
>   If any element in value is null, an empty string is used instead.

If you don't want null or empty entries, do like this:

```
return String.Join(separator, retList.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace(x));
```

Comment: In addition to this, you might want to use some LINQ to remove empty / null strings before calling `String.Join`.  `return String.Join(separator, retList.Find(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray());`

Comment: I added just this when you posted your comment :)